# Simple date with Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: postgresql, symfony, date, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I have a form with Sonata Admin Bundle with a date, to set the birthday of the user we want to add. Here goes `MemberAdmin.php` :

```
/**
 * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper $formMapper
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->with('General')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('name')
            ->add('surname')
            ->add('birthdate', 'birthday', array('format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
            // ...
}
```

And my problem is when I send the form, I obtain `Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object` ... But if I do `print_r($birthdate)` in the Entity class it shows me the `DateTime` object ...

Here are the interesting Entity parts:

```
/**
 * @var date
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="birthdate", type="date", nullable=true, options={"default" = "1990-01-01 00:00:00"})
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */
private $birthdate;


/**
 * Set birthdate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $birthdate
 * @return Membre
 */
public function setBirthdate($birthdate)
{
    $this->birthdate = $birthdate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get birthdate
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getBirthdate()
{
    return $this->birthdate;
}
```

My problem, currently, is that I don't know what I should do, I just want the date, no time, no anything else, i don't know if the column should be date (I work with PostgreSQL). What should I use for the types of my variables, I feel lost here, no simple `Date` possible ??

I tried to figure out from where it could come, but when I change too much I end up with: `This form should not contain extra fields` directly in the form, or even `Incorrect value`, but the field is a valid date ...

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

As @rande said, modifying vendors files is not the way to go, it provided an easy temp workaround for a local private app. As it is not dedicated to stay like that, I took care of the issue once I had more time. Sorry for the delay to come back to you guys.

I played around, tried with multiple setups, it took me time to figure it out, but I finally came to the conclusion that the issue... was caused by another date, that I was generating wrong in the constructor one line above.

Also, thanks to all of you, that guided me on the right path!

Answer (score 1):

Change your field type to sonata_type_date_picker and test if the error message persist.

```
 ->add('birthdate', 'sonata_type_date_picker', array(
              'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
              'widget' => 'single_text',
              'label' => 'Birthdate',

          ))
```

Comment: I tried, not a lot of doc available around it, even less about the new error occuring: a simple `An error has occurred during the creation of item` ... I tried playing around, but the errors just become even more crazy. Thanks for helping ^^" (the problem is not in the logs of pgsql nor symfony)

Answer (score 0):

From manual ([sonata-project.org](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_field_definition.html)) :

> If no type is set, the Admin class will use the one set in the
>   doctrine mapping definition.

So, you can try this:

```
->add('birthdate', null, array('format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have the same problem, `Call to a member function format() on a non-object`. At first, why does it tell me it's a non object ? I double checked, and print_r still gives me a DateTime object ...

Comment: Try add construct to your entity: `public function __construct()
    {
        $this-> birthdate = new \DateTime();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

@wr0ng.name you should never overwrite vendor code. NEVER.

There is something wrong with your mapping somewhere. You can use doctrine's commands to check your entity.

Comment: Just to let you know, the app wasn't dedicated to go public like that, the solution I gave was a quick workaround to not get stuck on it, I know it is far from being a clean way.
Also, I kept investigating and fixed it properly, see my edited answer ;-) Thanks for your guidance!!